# How to set first 4 items from recyclerView to visibility gone?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually, I have a menu from which I can add in my MainActivity buttons in a recyclerView an in that menu I'm showing all added buttons so one can delete chosen button.

But I have 4 first items of that recyclerView that should be default so no one should touch them, to manage it I've made that if on swipe position equals from 0 to 3 I will do nothing but I would hide them from that recyclerView and just show the added items.

[image]

Like as you can see on that drawing 1 is my MainActivity with 4 Default items and above them, I'm showing the added one, while the 2nd is my SettingsActivity where I'm adding the extra items but for now it's showing even the default that I would hide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How RecyclerView concept works on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042926/how-recyclerview-concept-works-on-android)

Comment: just use some flag isVisible in your dataset and on the basis of that toggle visibility of each item of recycler view in bind view holder function

Comment: Add and remove data from the list which you are passing to the adapter and set notifyDataSetChanged after that to reflect the result.

Comment: @Kunu i can't delete the data because i have to keep the items position

Comment: @Killer that would be a cool solution i'll try it immediatly

Comment: in your adapter `onBindViewHolder` set a counter which will increment on every call and a condition which will check the counter if it is <= 4 in this condition set the visibility to `gone` or you can just delete the first four elements from the list which you are adding in the adapter

Comment: @sourabhkaushik so just something like this in onBindViewHolder        int i = 0;
        i++;
        if(i <= 4){
            holder.box.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
?

Comment: @Killer that's working but there remain a white space as the items are just set to INVISIBLE ant not GONE

Comment: https://imgur.com/lav0UKd that's what is going on with VISIBILITY GONE, how can i even delete that white space?

Comment: what is the datatype Array u send to adapter and what is the data ArrayList content

Comment: ArrayList is of tree Strings and two Int

Comment: @JohnKarry ArrayList hashmap can you type the datatype like this for more explain to me sir EX > ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to manipulate the backing array so the `RecyclerView` just doesn't know about the missing views. A second way is to assign a different view type with zero height to those positions that are missing. One type for visible positions and another for invisible ones. The following is an example adapter that implements this concept:

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mItems;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public @NonNull
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        if (viewType == INVISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE) {
            // The type is invisible, so just create a zero-height Space widget to hold the position.
            view = new Space(parent.getContext());
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemViewHolder vh = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        String itemText = mItems.get(position);

        if (vh.getItemViewType() == VISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE) {
            // Only populate if a visible type.
            vh.mItemTextView.setText(itemText);
            int bgColor = (position % 2 == 0)
                ? android.R.color.holo_blue_light
                : android.R.color.holo_green_light;
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(bgColor));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mItems == null) ? 0 : mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // First 4 position don't show. The visibility of a position can be separately
        // determined if only, say, the first and third position should be invisible.
        return (position < 4) ? INVISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE : VISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE;
    }

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mItemTextView;

        ItemViewHolder(View item) {
            super(item);
            mItemTextView = item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }

    private final static int VISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE = 1;
    private final static int INVISIBLE_ITEM_TYPE = 2;
}
```

I would post a video, but it will just show the `RecyclerView` starting at item #4.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my level of understanding of your problem statement, you can use below code inside `onBindViewHolder` of adapter class to hide first 4 items.

Where `rootView` will be parent view of your recycler view item in `xml`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (position <= 3) {
        holder.rootView.setVisiblity(GONE);
    }
    else {
        holder.rootView.setVisiblity(VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's hidem them but in the recyclerView there is a big white space as the items are set to INVISIBLE and not GONE

Comment: Why you should use INVISIBLE? Why not GONE?

Comment: i'm using GONE, but seems like as you can see in the screen that item's are just hidden

Comment: @IgorMytyuk having the same exact issue. I'm using GONE, although it retains the space behind the list item. Have you resolved this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
before removing it save those records in another ArrayList say BackupArrayList then Remove it as below
    if (recyclerList.size() > 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            BackUpArrayList.add(recyclerList.get(i));
            recyclerList.remove(i);
        }
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```