# sectioned recycler view adapter, hide empty sections

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

my issue is very similar to this:
https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/issues/130

what i want to do is hide empty sections, i've tried various ways to do that, but i'm failing it constantly. I believe someone could instantly point out what i must do in order to hide a section that's empty.

```
    val headerHolder = holder as HeaderViewHolder
    if (sectionItemsTotal<=1){
        headerHolder.itemView.cl_lesson_header.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.itemView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

this works, but shows empty views instead.
tried             sectionAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
but it doesn't really help the case.

Comment: Wy you do not just remove that item?

Comment: You need to flag those “hidden/empty” views then when in `getViewType` return a constant that says it’s hidden. Then in `onCreateView` do nothing if the view/row is meant to be hidden.

Comment: sakiboy, can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to remove an item from a`RecyclerView`, so you won't have to worry about hiding it. If you don't remove the item from the `RecyclerView` then, to hide it, you would have to return some zero-height view from `onCreateViewHolder()`. (zero-width if horizontal)

You can search for "hiding items RecyclerView" to get some hits on this topic. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666801/how-to-set-first-4-items-from-recyclerview-to-visibility-gone/52668953#52668953) as an example.